# Calling Domino interop crashes calling application and Lotus Notes Client

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lotus-notes, com-interop

Our application wants to show appointments from Lotus Notes in a calendar. We do this by using Domino.interop. For some users all running Notes 9.0.1FP2 the application sometimes just dies.

The usual scenario is that the user open the calendar to show Notes appointments, then he navigates to another page in the application. After this he leaves the application alone for an hour or so, then when coming back and refreshing the application, it just silently closes without showing an error message. Then the Notes System Debugger kicks in and logs some errors. It says there is a ACCESS_VIOLATION. After that the Notes Client crashes.

Our application is written in C# and we listen to unhandled Thread exceptions as well as AppDomain.UnhandledException event. No such event happens.

When I access Domino.interop it is done as a COM in process call, which of course can cause the calling application to crash, but how can it make the Notes Client crash as well? After all it is a different process.

It feels something strange is going on here.

Comment: Have you contacted IBM Technical Support to open an incident with them? The Notes client should be saving data (an .nsd file, and some others) in the IBM Technical Support folder, which they should be able help you interpret.  As for why the Notes Client crashes in addition to your process, there's not really full isolation between the client and a standalone process using Notes APIs. There's a lot of shared memory behind the scenes in the Notes core DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simalar Problem.

When you call `Session.GetDatabase()` the exception gets thrown in one of it's sub Threads.
Here is what helped me:

1. Deinstalling Lotus Notes
2. Backing up my local Database files
   This [website](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/app_important_files_to_backup_r.html) should give you a good overview on what might be important to keep. It is in german but it should help never the less.
3. Deleting Registry entries
   I deleted  entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
   Just look for `Software` and you should find IBM there.
   Some more IBM stuff was hidden in `HKEY-LOCAL-MACHINE --> SOFTWARE --> Wow6432Node`.
4. Reinstalling Lotus Notes

This wrapped up the problem for me nice and neatly.
The real source of the bug is yet to be discoverd...